# GWT now has spring roo support, what will this mean to GWT developers?

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, spring-roo

I have been using GWT with App Engine for a while now. Recently there was an [announcement](http://googlewebtoolkit.blogspot.com/2010/05/gwt-21-milestone-1-is-now-available.html) that GWT will support Spring Roo and SpringSource Tool Suite. I am having trouble seeing the big picture from the Google announcement page. For those without much knowledge of Spring what does this mean for GWT developers used to building swing-like gui's?

Answer (score 2):

My understanding is that Spring-Roo simplifies creating the server side component as well as making a rudimentary GWT front end for you.  Then as a GWT developer, you can take the generated GWT front end and further embellish it.  So, if is as good as they say it is, it makes your life as a GWT developer much easier and makes you more productive.

Answer (score 2):

My first impression on Spring Roo is just a code generator. But after I learn a few things about the files AspectJ created in the project, my view was totally changed. I took one ERD diagram from databaseanswer.com and created the entities with Roo, generate the web controller. Straight away I got an application within minutes. All I needed was an ERD diagram and what I got is the well written application in Java based on the fact that AspectJ codes are Java codes. If I want to write the complex code for reporting. I can write them either in one of the Entities or custom service classes. Not only GWT, any support or add-on Roo will ease my development. Struts 2 addon for Spring Roo in the future ? Yes, please.

Answer (score 1):

I think that this alliance enables developers to design complex and high performing applications even more easier. Concering GWT applications Spring would offer the server-side part with the many aspects provided by the framework (e.g. dependency injection, architecture, securits, data access ...) you might need in an enterprise application. 
As far as I understand Spring Roo is a framework for rapid developement. Using GWT in combination with this, GAE and other mentioned spring technologies you'll be able to quickly start developing app engine applications (for example).